# Force a client to call a specific method

Tags: javascript, typescript, design-patterns

How do I force a client to call the `build` method at the end of the command chain?

```js
const foo = new Foo();
foo.bar().a() // I want to make sure that the `build` method was called.
```

Here's my example:

```js
interface IFoo {
    bar(): IBar;
    build(): string;
}

class Foo {
    public commands;

    constructor() {
        this.commands = []
    }

    public bar(): any {
        return new Bar(this);
    }

    public build(): any {
        return this.commands.join(' ')
    }

}
```

```js
interface IBar {
    a(): IFoo
}

class Bar {
    private foo: Foo;

    constructor(foo){
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    public a(): IFoo {
        this.foo.commands.push('something')
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: (1) By explaining it in the docs, and (2) by making sure that the "thing" that your users want is only returned by calling `build()` and/or (3) by adding a flag that prevents using the "thing" until `build()` is called (which sets the flag).

Comment: Thank you for looking into my question. Can you please help with the example for point #3? How do i implement this flag?

Comment: Your build() returns a string, and a string can't contain a flag, so it's a bit difficult in such a case. I'm guessing your users **want the string result**, so why would they *not* call `build()`? They'd be stupid to go through backdoors instead. And if they want to use backdoors, well then don't provide support if they mess up in such a way.

Comment: @AnonymousAnonymous You can never force a consumer to use a part of your API. Why do you want to force them to use the `build` method?

Comment: @PeterB Got it. Thank you for your answer. Exactly, the `build` method is the one that returns a string and this is something that a client needs. In this case, the explanation is docs would be sufficient.

Comment: @jsejcksn well, the reason is that I want to make sure that a client receives the correct result when using my API. The way I've designed the API without calling the `build` method a user would be able to do it. That's why I'm looking for a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Peter said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71211809/force-a-client-to-call-a-specific-method#comment125875790_71211809), just structure your API such that it provides no utility to a consumer except in the ways you desire:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8BQ1oAcBOB7ALgsIQCbTC4C2lYAdiRAFzQT7YCWtA5gNoC6AblTpyuWq2wBXYrmzQAFBWp0GAfmYTOvPgEoUIjPgAW7CADolNejAC8o5deirV0fkIwBfYRkySARiDswNB+kuwgZPI6Gmxa+hgY2Aj4kti00MamFlRWDGYAVric8gDk0CU67tBeIjjsAG5ghBm4AMqx3ArRLB1c8QlJKWkZJuah4SRRVTU+HI3N+LgAUq0A8gByXTEc3Pz9icmp6ZnmlioQ06g1oJAwAGK4uNAIAB6EjvAQSGg+-oHBfjAciizHgch+A0Ow1oCAA7nAgfITtkHAxKiIvNdwFAEXJXu8GAivv1fAEgtAwFtoA8nhDDKMUblzL4IEZShAqMkTNwKlUDkN0jD4TSkQyztZ0Z4rsJUAB6WXQACqX0Ywgo4nw0AAZo9oHYhdTHlNUOrWCEgXrtY8zIDsMbTZq6AQjAhsDTLTrcDbETozGB7WIzeKyHYncZXTSbWEIsbUGGXW7rcGLtBZQAqAwJLPQAB6efzedQAAU8JhXfgAJ7lZNlUxYPCEYgIMgqaBiEBVsDAYAIKDsAJIWHsTLpG44kqfBBlVvDmAQfxjr7meQAJgALGuAKx6NOytWB3AgBBmEC4LiKHIqSqphUAIg5lC5WlvJoPR5PZ-kKw2Zk03HYWoVvI8YRo8OjXvK5Q8PenIjlwt58CUr7iIex6nue7Q7OeIGJrg4ECDe0AwY+cEvkAA)

```ts
class Base {
  protected commands: string[];

  constructor (commands?: string[]) {
    this.commands = commands ?? [];
  }

  public build (): string {
    return this.commands.join(' ');
  }

  private toString (): string {
    return this.build();
  }

  private toJSON (): string[] {
    return this.commands;
  }
}

class Foo extends Base {
  public bar (): Bar {
    return new Bar(this.commands);
  }
}

class Bar extends Base {
  public a (): Foo {
    this.commands.push('something');
    return new Foo(this.commands);
  }
}


// Use:

const foo = new Foo();
const bar = foo.bar();
const anotherFoo = foo.bar().a();
const command = anotherFoo.build();

anotherFoo.commands; /*
           ^^^^^^^^
Property 'commands' is protected and only accessible within class 'Base' and its subclasses.(2445) */

console.log(command); // "something"
console.log(JSON.stringify(anotherFoo)); // '["something"]'
console.log(String(anotherFoo)); // "something"
```